# .htaccess and permanent redirection issues

Tags: seo, htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect

I have a WordPress website hosted on Bluehost which contains the following URL pattern:

```
http://www.example.com/2017/01/30/sample-post/
```

I want to permanent redirect it to use this:

```
http://www.example.com/sample-post/
```

So I opened `.htaccess` kept in the `example.com` folder and changed it to this

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/$ http://www.example.com/$1

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Then I went to my Permalink Settings in the Wordpress admin and changed my "Common Settings" from  "Day and name" to "Custom Structure"
`/%postname%/`

Now when I access `http://www.example.com/2017/01/30/sample-post/` it gives me

> 404 | Page Not Found! Sorry, but the page you were looking for is not
>   here.

And when I access the URL directly `http://www.example.com/sample-post/` 
it gives me

> too many redirects error.

Where am I goofing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/$ http://www.example.com/$1
> ```

The *pattern* `^/([^/]+)/$` doesn't match the URL-path `/2017/01/30/sample-post/`, so these URLs will not be redirected. However, it does match `/sample-post/` - which is why you get the redirect loop.

However, `RedirectMatch` is also a mod_alias directive, not mod_rewrite. (`RewriteEngine` does not apply.) You should change this to a mod_rewrite directive to avoid potential conflicts and unexpected results. (Different Apache modules execute at different times, despite their apparent order in the config file.)

So, try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d/(.+) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This specifically matches a URL of the form `/2017/01/30/sample-post/` (the trailing slash is not enforced). Your redirect would have actually *stripped* the trailing slash.

Make sure your browser cache is cleared before testing. Change the `302` to a `301` only when you are sure it's working OK. (`302`s avoid being cached.)

Comment: I have a follow up question if you don;t mind. After I wrote this rewrite rule, everything of the url format http://www.somewebsite.com/2017/01/30/sample-post/ works great. However if the url has the format http://www.somewebsite.com/name-of-category/2008/10/20/sample-post/. it is throwing a 404. I want it to permanent redirect to http://www.somewebsite.com/name-of-category/sample-post/. What change do i need to make?

Comment: I moved my update to your new question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104460/htaccess-and-permanent-redirection-with-a-special-condition