# .htaccess and permanent redirection with a special condition

Tags: seo, htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress website hosted on Bluehost which contains the following URL pattern:

```
http://www.example.com/2017/01/30/sample-post/
```

I wanted to permanent redirect it to use this:

```
http://www.example.com/sample-post/
```

So I opened `.htaccess` kept in the `example.com` folder and changed it to the following with the help of a [suggestion by w3dk](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/103331/1243).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d/(.+) /$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

After I wrote this rewrite rule, everything of the URL format `example.com/2017/01/30/sample-post` works great. However, there are a few URLs in the website that have the format `example.com/name-of-category/2008/10/20/sample-post` and are throwing a 404 as the result of the above rewrite rule.

I want to permanently redirect `www.example.com/name-of-category/2008/10/20/sample-post` to `www.example.com/name-of-category/sample-post`.

What change do I need to make in my `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle category posts of the form `/name-of-category/2008/10/20/sample-post` then include something like the following directive after the existing redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d/(.+) /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This would redirect `/name-of-category/2008/10/20/sample-post` to `/name-of-category/sample-post`. Note that the *category* consists of just the lowercase `a`-`z` and the `-` (hyphen), as in your example.

If you needed to allow more characters in the category then changing `[a-z-]` to `[\w-]` in the above `RewriteRule` *pattern* would allow `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`, `0`-`9`, `_` and `-`. But it is better to be as restrictive as possible.

So, in summary:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d/(.+) /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d/(.+) /$1/$2 [R=301,L]

:
```

Comment: I tried it..the 404 goes away. So thanks for that. But what's happening now is example.com/name-of-category/2008/10/20/sample-post gets redirected to example.com/name-of-category/sample-post which gets redirected to example.com/sample-post.

Comment: What do your category URLs look like within WordPress? The `/name-of-category/sample-post` to `/sample-post` redirect would seem to be triggered by WordPress itself?

Comment: I don't seem to find anything that suggests that. When I open a category, there is no redirect. It just opens as-is. However when I open a post within a category like example.com/name-of-category/2008/10/20/sample-post, the redirection occurs and both the category and date are lost. i want to retain the category.

Comment: To clarify, when you open a page within a category on your site, then URL is of the form: `/name-of-category/sample-post`? Try (temporarily) changing the status code of these two redirects to 307 (ie. `R=307`). Clear your browser cache and view the network traffic in the browser dev tools. What redirects/status do you see when requesting a URL of the form `/name-of-category/2008/10/20/sample-post`?